# Skipping INF values in 2d array Python

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I am currently working with a data set that contains a lot of 'INF' values that are messing up my calculations. I've tried to remove these values, but I have been unable to find a way to do this with a 2D array. Some of my code is below:

```
def date2str(date_str):
    date = datetime.strptime(date_str, '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
    return date.toordinal()

def readfiles(file_list):
    data = []
    for fname in file_list:
        data.append(
                    np.loadtxt(fname,
                               usecols=(0,18),
                               comments='#',    # skip comment lines
                               delimiter='\t',
                               converters = { 0 : date2str },
                               dtype=None))
    return data

data = readfiles(['soundTransit1_remote_rawMeasurements_15m.txt'])
print data
data = data[np.isfinite(data)]
np.set_printoptions(threshold='nan')

column_0 = np.array(data)[0][:,0]
column_1 = np.array(data)[0][:,1]

thermTemp1_degC = 1/(1.401E-3 + 2.377E-4*np.log(column_1) + 9.730E-8*np.log(column_1)**3)-273.15
```

I have read in two of the columns (one containing data and the other containing the associated date and time) and separated them so I could manipulate the data (on the last line of my code). I need to be able to skip the lines of my data that contain 'INF'. The current solution I have, 'data = data[np.isfinite(data)] is not working. I receive the error 'TypeError: only integer arrays with one element can be converted to an index'. Can anyone give me some guidance?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your function `readfiles` returns a python list, not a numpy array.  Python lists can not be indexed with one of numpy's boolean arrays, which is why you get the error with `data[np.isfinite(data)]`; `data` is a python list, but `np.isfinite(data)` is a numpy array of boolean values.

Either return a numpy array from `readfiles` with something like

```
return np.array(data)
```

or convert the result to an array before you try to use numpy's boolean indexing:

```
data = np.array(data)
data = data[np.isfinite(data)]
```

You might have to the massage the list a bit to get an array with the desired shape.